# Image Getting Stretched when trying to Resize It keeping the aspect Ratio

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

Im using the following code to resize an image preserving the aspect ratio

```
 public Bitmap resizeImage(System.Drawing.Image imgToResize, SizeF size)
        {
            int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
            int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

            float nPercent = 0;
            float nPercentW = 0;
            float nPercentH = 0;

            nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
            nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
                nPercent = nPercentH;
            else
                nPercent = nPercentW;

            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b);

            // Used to Prevent White Line Border 

           // g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
            g.Dispose();

            return b;
        }
```

But images with large width gets compressed and the contents seem packed up into a small space.What im trying to achieve is this : ***Resize the Large Size/Large Resolution image because processing this will take huge time,So when the image width or height exceeds say 1000 i want to resize the image to a Smaller size eg:1000 Width or Height which ever is larger,so that i can save computation time.But it seems the above code is forcibly trying to fit the image into the 1000X1000 Box when i do***

```
if (y.Width > 1000 || y.Height > 1000)
{

y = new Bitmap( resizeImage(y, new Size(1000, 1000)));

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Comment: You have to determine the scale the image should be resized by and set the new dimensions based on that calculation.

Comment: @TheGeneral Actually im calling another method that takes integer parameters, it should be `resizeImage(y, new Size(1000, 1000))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, its a bit neater

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap source, Size size)
{
   var scale = Math.Min(size.Width / (double)source.Width, size.Height / (double)source.Height);   
   var bmp = new Bitmap((int)(source.Width * scale), (int)(source.Height * scale));

   using (var graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
   {
      graph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
      graph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
      graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
      graph.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
   }
   return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Will check and revert.

Comment: Why use graph and return bmp?

Comment: @Fredy that graphics obj is related the result bmp, so drawning on is drawing on the result.

Comment: @TheGeneral well, in my case it wouldn't work... But I found what I needed in another SO thread (there are many on this subject). Many thanks for your reply.